# I tried to run the code but the result printed on the console isn't what I expect it to be. I'm stucked

Tags: java

When I run the code the result printed on the console isn't what I expect it to be. I've tried reiterating this few times. Now I'm stucked. I thought I nailed down everything but when the result show it's not correct. Can you help me ?

```
public class Battleships_revision {
    public static String[][] ocean = new String[10][10];
    public static String[][] ocean2 = new String[10][10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        intro();
    }

    public static void intro() {
        System.out.println("\n**** Welcome to Battle Ships game ****");
        System.out.println("\nRight now, the sea is empty.\n");
        printMap(ocean);
    }

    public static void printMap(String[][] ocean){
        System.out.println("\n  0123456789  ");
        for(int row=0; row<ocean.length; row++){ //Create the numbers on the grid:
            System.out.println(row+"|");
            for (int col=0; col<ocean[row].length; col++){
                if(ocean[row][col]==null){
                    System.out.println(" ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(ocean[row][col]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("|"+row);
        }
        System.out.println("  0123456789  ");
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a `newLine` for every `column` in a `row`. Instead, append `newLine` only at the end of a `row`

```
public static void printMap(String[][] ocean){
    System.out.println("\n  0123456789  ");
    for(int row=0; row<ocean.length; row++){ //Create the numbers on the grid:
        System.out.print(row+"|");
        for (int col=0; col<ocean[row].length; col++){
            if(ocean[row][col]==null){
                System.out.print(" ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(ocean[row][col]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("|"+row);
    }
    System.out.println("  0123456789  ");
}
```